# Internals of deleting a document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch's documentation [Updating a document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html) says:

> Internally, Elasticsearch has marked the old document as deleted and
>   added an entirely new document. The old version of the document
>   doesn’t disappear immediately, although you won’t be able to access
>   it. Elasticsearch cleans up deleted documents in the background as you
>   continue to index more data.

An in [Deleting a document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/delete-doc.html):

> deleting a document doesn’t immediately remove the document from
>   disk; it just marks it as deleted. Elasticsearch will clean up deleted
>   documents in the background as you continue to index more data.

Does this mean that if we never index anything, the data will be stored and marked for deletion forever but never deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can still completely delete non-indexed documents as long as they're marked for deletion. Use the following command -

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

Forcemerge used to be 'optimize' but that is now depreciated.